# Song of india spots and burnt signs on leaves help please

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, pests

I stay in kolkata right now the temperature is 30 and humidity level is 31. Its been 1 week i bought my plant from the nursery and i repotted it yesterday and i see some spots and burnt on my plant leaves. To my knowledge i did not overwater it and kept it in my balcony.

If anyone can help me out please do reply.song of india leaf spots[image]